# I am anable to replace comment- in php

Tags: php

> $string = "comment-454";

I want to disply only 454? not **comment-**

i  am saving in db comment-454 , now i want to crop comment-.. how can i

can someone provide me something, because i am newbie in php..
thanks in advance..

Comment: Where's the *"I tried this but it didn't work:* part?

Comment: Use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to remove part of a string. Next time take the time to search on Google, this is very easy to find.

Comment: Déjà vu @ can you give me the code?

Comment: -1 just for asking for code.

Comment: cant find anything.. @ Drown can you provide me anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$string = str_replace("comment-", "", "comment-454");

should replace what you want.

you mentioned `comment-454` came from your database. So ill assume it's in `$result`.

Now you can do:

```
$string = str_replace("comment-", "", $result);

echo $string;
```

Comment: if this worked for you, you should accept the answer by cliccking the ✓ next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use explote() http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php

$teile = explode("-", $string);
echo $teile[1]; // 454